# Re-position DIVs into their first place after drag and drop using jQuery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have set draggable for 5 dIVs and by each drag and drop one div moves to the target place. How can I set the init function so that by pressing "Play Again!" the dropped card go back to where it was at the beginning before drag and drop.

Here is the link to my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/k9NXv/2/

```
function init()
{
      $('#successMessage').hide();
  $('#successMessage').css( {
    left: '580px',
    top: '250px',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  } );
    //Resetting the game
    var faces = ['happy','mad','sad','worried','guilty'];


    for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        $('#' + faces[i] + '').draggable({

            stack: '#faceSlot',
            cursor: 'move',
            revert: true
      });
    }

        $('#faceSlot').droppable({
                hoverClass: 'hovered',
                drop: handleCardDrop
                });
};
```

Comment: Is it possible just to reload the drag and page content?

Comment: yes, How can I accomplish this?

Comment: See my answer beloqw. Just add page refresh to function init()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your current page use:

```
<div id="mainContainer"> 
</div>
$(load);
function load(){
$.get( "../YourContent.html", function( data ) {
  $( "#mainContainer" ).html( data );
  $(init);
});
}
```

Create a seperate page called: YourContent.html
On this page include:

```
function init()
{
      $('#successMessage').hide();
  $('#successMessage').css( {
    left: '580px',
    top: '250px',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  } );
    //Resetting the game
    var faces = ['happy','mad','sad','worried','guilty'];


    for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        $('#' + faces[i] + '').draggable({

            stack: '#faceSlot',
            cursor: 'move',
            revert: true
      });
    }

        $('#faceSlot').droppable({
                hoverClass: 'hovered',
                drop: handleCardDrop
                });
};

function handleCardDrop(event,ui) 
{
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    $('#successMessage').show();
    $('#successMessage').animate( {
      left: '380px',
      top: '200px',
      width: '400px',
      height: '100px',
      opacity: 1
    } );
   $(load);
};
```

This way, when your page loads, it uses the Load() function to retrieve the page with the script and the game on it, when you want to reset the game, you just call the load() function. You may have to keep your vairables outside that function, but this shoudl give you an idea of the basic setup/